# Date object value is changes -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, date, reactjs

I am doing a unit test on a component that receive date as a variable. My test fails because the ate variable in the actual and expected object keeps adding few milliseconds to the date value.

```
describe('Clock',()=>{
    it('works',()=>{
        let renderer = createRenderer();
        let date = new Date();


        renderer.render(<Clock time={ date}> </Clock>);
        let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();

        let expectedElement = <FormattedTime value={date} hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric" />;

        expect(actualElement).toEqual(expectedElement);
    });
});
```

When i run my test . IN the above, it shows the expectedElement `date` added some few milliseconds.

```
-    "value": [Date: 2016-01-28T04:48:57.000Z]
+    "value": [Date: 2016-01-28T04:48:57.893Z]
```

Please how do i make the date tally ? Or better get rid of the milli seconds . I tried many opetions like

```
let date = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
let rTime = new Date(date * 1000);

renderer.render(<Clock time={ rTime}> </Clock>);
let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();

let expectedElement = <FormattedTime value={rTime} hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric" />;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
Hi , below is my clock as requested . 
    export default class Clock extends React.Component {

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            time: new Date(),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: new Date() }), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    render() {
        const { time } = this.state;
        return (
            <FormattedTime value={time} hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric" />
        );
    }
}
```

I use the `date.setMilliseconds(0)` suggested below and then i realized the Clock component is returning with the 0. so i had to change my test to the one below.

```
describe('Clock',()=>{
    it('works',()=>{
        let renderer = createRenderer();
        let date = new Date();
        date.setMilliseconds(0)

        renderer.render(<Clock time={ date}> </Clock>);
        let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        let expectedElement = <FormattedTime value={date} hour="numeric" minute="numeric" second="numeric" />;
        actualElement.props.value.setMilliseconds(0);
        expect(actualElement).toEqual(expectedElement);
    });
});
```

Now its working . Thank you for your time. Btw i am running and reacjs and `react-addons-test-utils` lib for testing.

Comment: Please show us the code that is responsible for the rendering, such as `Clock`, `FormattedTime` and the `renderer`.

Comment: In what environment are you running this?

Comment: `date.setMilliseconds(0)` should suffice; but doesn't getting rid of the milliseconds work?

Comment: @Bergi it works now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of milliseconds simply set them to zero : 'date.setMilliseconds (0)'

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds)

Comment: That will work until the difference in milliseconds is greater than 1 second. Far better to find out why there are differences at all (which the OP hasn't provided enough information for).